# Matlab insert missing data into timeseries object

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have a timeseries, whereas the time is stored in the `datenum` format. The `datenum` vector has been constructed from a `datetime` vector with the format `"dd-MMM-yyy HH:MM:SS`". Since my data has a 1-minute frequency, I need 1440 data points and the corresponding time in my timeseries for each day. However, some days have a couple data points missing (usually not more than 5), which I need to fill manually.

Thus, I have the following questions:

1. How can I fetch daily data from the timeseries (I have tried using `getsampleusingtime` with `unique date values` based solely on dates, however this won't work).
2. How can I identify the missing values based upon the `datenum` time in my timeseries for each day and then insert the respective time with a datapoint "0"?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example (not programmed nicely...):

```
clc; clear;

time = {};

% Sample time series
for d = 1:3
    for h = 0:23
        if h < 10
            hstr = ['0' num2str(h)];
        else
            hstr = num2str(h);
        end
        for m = 0:59
            if m < 10
                mstr = ['0' num2str(m)];
            else
                mstr = num2str(m);
            end
            time{end+1,1} = ['0' num2str(d) '-01-2016 ' hstr ':' mstr ':00'];
        end
    end
end

% Missing times
time([10 2000]) = [];

input_format = 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss';

num = datenum(datetime(time,'InputFormat',input_format));
```

You can now check for values of a specific day if you calculate the `datenum` of the beginning of the day and the beginning of the next day. All values in between belong the the selected day.

```
% Check for second day (1.)
test1 = '02-01-2016 00:00:00';
test2 = '03-01-2016 00:00:00';

num1 = datenum(datetime(test1,'InputFormat',input_format));
num2 = datenum(datetime(test2,'InputFormat',input_format));

% Find all in one day
r = num>=num1 & num<num2;

day2 = num(r); % Only the values from the second day.
```

To find missing values, you can calculate the delta of 1 minute and search for all values, where the difference is larger.

```
% Find missing values (2.)
test1 = '01-01-2016 00:00:00';
test2 = '01-01-2016 00:01:00';

num1 = datenum(datetime(test1,'InputFormat',input_format));
num2 = datenum(datetime(test2,'InputFormat',input_format));

delta = num2-num1;

% Find missing values
pos = find(diff(num) > delta*1.1); % To avoid numerical issues
```

Note, the second example only works if for all the same value of the seconds are used (as in my case `00`).

EDIT:

Another option is to use the `datetime` structure directly.

```
dates = datetime(time,'InputFormat',input_format);

% 1.
day2 = find([dates.Day] == 2);

% 2.
pos = find(diff([dates.Minute])>1);
```